# remembering multiple fields in python pattern matching

Tags: python, regex

This is such a basic perl capability I've gotta believe you can do it in python but I can't find anything in the docs, unless of course it's implied...

Here's a very simple example of parsing a time field in a string:

```
time=re.search("(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", variable)
```

I do understand if successful a match object will be created.  But what I can't find is a way to find out the values that matched the 3 patterns so I can stuff them into variables like hours, mins and secs.  All the usage examples I found only show 1 set of ()s.

-mark

Answer (score 7):

[`match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) objects have a [`groups`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) method that returns a tuple:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = re.search("(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", variable).groups()
```

Comment: +1 for tuple unpacking from groups() to the individual variables.

Comment: Note that this will give you string values, if you want integers you can use `map(int, ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `groups` method to get the matching groups

```
>>> variable = '1:2:3'
>>> time=re.search("(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", variable)
>>> print time
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f3917211918>
>>> print time.groups()
('1', '2', '3')
```

If you just want the first group:

```
>>> print time.group(1)
1
```

or the second group (`time.group(2)`) etc.  Note that these are always strings.

---

You can even name the groups if you want to:

```
>>> time=re.search("(?P<HR>\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", variable)
>>> time.group("HR")
'1'
```

Comment: `time.group(0)` will return the entire match, while the individual groups can be retrieved using 1-based numbering

Answer (score 3):

Use [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) or [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
import time
stime = time.strptime(variable, '%H:%M:%S')
hours, minutes, seconds = stime.tm_hour, stime.tm_min, stime.tm_sec
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use named groups:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("(?P<hours>\d+):(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d+)")
>>> time = re.search(pattern, "12:34:56")
>>> time.group("hours")
'12'
>>> time.group("minutes")
'34'
>>> time.group("seconds")
'56'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do you one better:

```
>>> import re
>>> variable = "12:34:56"
>>> time = re.search("(?P<hours>\d+):(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d+)", variable)
>>> time.group('hours')
'12'
```

See the [docs for `re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m.groups()` to list all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

wow - I figured it out.  I'm sure this is obvious to seasoned users but for a newbie like me I never would have thought of this.  The 3 values are stored in time.group(1), 2 and 3.